# How do I find out the duplex mode / speed of an ethernet interface under Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, duplex

I want to find out the duplex mode / speed of an etherenet interface or a bridge interface. And I want to change them also. I can not use tools like `ethtool` or `mii` because my system does not have a such tools and I can not install them.

Are there a solution for that (like using /proc)?

Comment: If you really can't install ethtool, only think left to do is to read sources of ethtool and do some c-programming on your own. I'd recommend that you install ethtool (either a package using package manager of your choice or compile if from sources), because anything else just makes things more laborous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dmesg` output e.g. `dmesg | grep -i duplex`

Ref: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-linux-lan-card-find-out-full-duplex-half-speed-or-mode/

Comment: duplex info could be lost in the dmesg because dmesg is a log

Comment: You're running out of options that aren't going to take a long time to write, when you could save yourself a lot of hassle and just get `ethtool` or `mii-tool`... what's the reasoning behind not being able to install either?